# Optimising code for finding the next prime number

Tags: python

I'm new to both Python and StackOverflow so I apologise if this question has been repeated too much or if it's not a good question. I'm doing a beginner's Python course and one of the tasks I have to do is to make a function that finds the next prime number after a given input. This is what I have so far:

```
def nextPrime(n):
        num = n + 1
    for i in range(1, 500):
        for j in range(2, num):
            if num%j == 0:
                num = num + 1
    return num
```

When I run it on the site's IDE, it's fine and everything works well but then when I submit the task, it says the runtime was too long and that I should optimise my code. But I'm not really sure how to do this, so would it be possible to get some feedback or any suggestions on how to make it run faster?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-different-methods-find-prime-number-python/ I'd recommend looking in your favorite search engine for "prime number algorithms"

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. I did do both of these things, I actually had tried a number of methods that I learnt from the course but I kept getting wrong outputs and most of the code that I found online was too complex for me to understand (since I am a complete beginner). Therefore, I decided to go on here because I was really stuck and the hints were not helping. I figured I would be able to come on here to get some constructive feedback on the code I wrote :)

Answer (score 1):

When your function finds the answer, it will continue checking the same number hundreds of times.  This is why it is taking so long.  Also, when you increase num, you should break out of the nested loop to that the new number is checked against the small factors first (which is more likely to eliminate it and would accelerate progress).

To make this simpler and more efficient, you should break down your problem in areas of concern.  Checking if a number is prime or not should be implemented in its own separate function.  This will make the code of your nextPrime() function much simpler:

```
def nextPrime(n):
    n += 1 
    while not isPrime(n): n += 1
    return n
```

Now you only need to implement an efficient isPrime() function:

```
def isPrime(x):
    p,inc = 2,1
    while p*p <= x:
        if x % p == 0: return False
        p,inc = p+inc,2
    return x > 1
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply, I really appreciate your help! This is definitely a lot faster than my original code and I see where I went wrong now :D I'm a little confused on this line: p,inc = p+inc,2 : what would this do and why would you include this? Sorry if this is a stupid question, by the way!

Comment: That's just a trick to go through divisors starting with 2 and then only going through odd numbers.  So `p` will first be incremented by 1 (going from 2 to 3) and then by 2 for all other divisors (3, 5, 7, ... only odd numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Looping from 1 to 500, especially because another loop runs through it, is not only inefficient, but also confines the range of the possible "next prime number" that you're trying to find. Therefore, you should make use of while loop and `break` which can be used to break out of the loop whenever you have found the prime number (of course, if it's stated that the number is less than 501 in the prompt, your approach totally makes sense).

Furthermore, you can make use of the fact that you only need check the integers less than or equal to the square root of the designated integer (which in python, is represented as `num**0.5`) to determine if that integer is prime, as the divisors of the integers always come in pair and the largest of the smaller divisor is always a square root, if it exists.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply, I really appreciate it! The prompt does say that the prime number inputs are in the range 1 to 500, so that's why I looped it. I think I'll try out using a while loop as you suggested and I'll get back to you on how that works out. Thank you for your help!